# How should I fill gaps in wooden skirting board etc?

Tags: wood, baseboard, wood-filler

I got [this product](https://www.lime.org.uk/general-purpose-filler-ty-mawr.html) to fill deep holes. It is a general purpose filler which states:

> This is a non-shrink, ready mixed mortar made with natural hydraulic lime, siliceous and calcareous sand (0-0.6mm) and additives. Suitable for repairing or restoring cement renders, lime plasters and refurbishment work on composite backgrounds.

Can I get away with using it to fill gaps in wooden skirting board or might it introduce problems?  I just need it to hold for a year or so. It would be for small holes in the skirting board as well as in between the board and wall. Just to block small lines of air flow that are coming up.

Comment: It depends on whether "wood skirting boards" and "etc." are stable surfaces. If they're subject to movement a cementitious product is likely to crack away. At any rate, this is really a product question, and therefore off-topic. I don't see how it can be abstracted to discuss only product _type_.

Comment: Is it listed as a "wood filler"? If so, then it's probably going to work just fine for filling holes in wood. If you're looking to fill a gap in the plaster/platerboard _behind_ the trim, then wood filler is _not_ the product you're looking for, but you may not need to _fill_ the gap, as opposed to just covering it.

Comment: Also, defining what "this product" is, instead of expecting people to click a link to see what it is, would help eliminate some of the confusion I note in my comment above. You're expecting free help, make it as easy on your helpers as possible by providing as much info as possible.

Comment: If you re-word your question to be "How should fill the gaps in my wood skirting boards"  It may be re-opened. You will need to add more details about your skirting then just "wooden".

Answer (score 1):

If you only need it to last "a year or so", use Playdough, chewing gum, Bondo™, duct tape, cement, lime or whatever the heck you want. If it falls out in 6 months, fill it again - this only has to last a year or so, right?

If you want to do it right, then use a quality wood filler. If you want to slap in whatever product you have sitting around the house, then slap it in.

The same holds true for fixing the holes in "etc". If it's just temporary, use whatever you've got on hand. Heck, you could probably make wood filler work just fine in a plaster wall if it's only for a year...